# Android: Killing background activities

Tags: java, android, back

I have an application that contains many game screens, each is its own activity. Some of these game screens will use timers to initiate some functionality. The problem I am having is when the user backs out of one of these game screens, the timers are still running in the background. I know this because when I leave to the main menu the timer loads up the losing screen because the timer and activity were still running in the background process. I simply want to kill the activity if the user hits the phone back button (Not a button I have created but the devices back button).

This is the current method I use to try and accomplish this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    this.finish();
}
```

It does not kill the activity.

EDIT:

I Should mention that stopping the timers does work but for some of my screens the win or lose conditions are done when a variable hits a certain number. For example, I have one screen that when an enemy escapes the view of the player a variable goes up by 1 when this hits 5 the player loses. This is not done on a timer, so because the activity is still running, the variable hits 5 and the losing screen is loaded when I am not on that game screen anymore.

Comment: check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Only the visible `Activity` will receive that `finish()` command. You need to start and stop your timers `onResume` and `onPause`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remove

```
super.onBackPressed();
```

And add

```
yourActivity.this.finish();
```

Let me know if that helps :)

Comment: did not get called i dont think

Comment: you mean onBackPressed() method is not being called?

Comment: when using this method inside onBackPressed it does not change the outcome, so either onBackPressed is not being called or the method you suggested is not working.

Comment: Kindly add this line at the start of onBackPressed() method and see the logs Log.i("backPressed","hello");

Comment: The back method is called but the method you gave does not seem to work

Comment: Let us continue this discussion in chat http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43810934/android-killing-background-acitivities/43811128?noredirect=1#